# How to test Alamofire on XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xctest

I'm learning how to properly unit test my methods. I have a version check method which will retrieve a JSON from Web Services. How do I go about it?

```
 //check for new version, compare if the current version is older than server version
    func checkNewVersion() {

        request(URLRouter.CheckForUpdate()).responseJSON {
            responseData in
            if responseData.result.isFailure
            {
                let alertController =  self.setActionPrompt("Network Error", message: "Error in signing in to tasker service", buttonText: "Retry", openLiveLab: false)
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                let j = JSON(data: responseData.data!)
                for (key,subJ) in j {
                    if key == kAppId
                    {
                        let serverVer = subJ["ver"].string!
                        let iosUrl = subJ["iosUrl"].string!
                        let ver = serverVer.compareVersion(kAppVer, ServerVer: serverVer) // compare if the current version is older than server version

                        if (ver) // if older
                        {
                            let alertController = self.setActionPromptWithURL("Update Available!",
                                message: "Please update APP to \nthe latest version \n\n Thank you!",
                                buttonText: "Update", url: iosUrl)
                            UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        else { self.loginServices() }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use OHTTPStubs for testing with alamofire: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs

Comment: [Here](http://swiftandpainless.com/another-approach-to-stubbing-nsurlsession-with-dependency-injection/) is how I test NSURLSession. Should also work with any closure based networking framework.